# Is there a framework that can be used in an app to identify sounds?

Tags: android, ios, audio, siri, shazam

I'm hoping to not get too many down votes for this question...

I've searches a bit but am at a loss.

I'm looking for a framework that can be used in an iOS or Android app that can identify sounds.

My scenario is:
In a room there are 3 speakers.
Each speaker plays its own unique sound (i.e. speaker A will always play sound A, speaker B will play sound B etc).
One of the 3 speakers, chosen at random plays a sound.
The app needs to identify which speaker played its sound.

I've seen bird song and music identification apps but I'm not sure what framework they use or what's needed to identify a certain sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite likely you are going to have to get your app to sample a few seconds of audio, then send that to an external api to verify what sound it was. Then from that you could say if it came from speaker x.
Maybe something like this:
http://echoprint.me/
But you would have to play a song.